# Jinja dipslay dictionary values in html by header from list

Tags: python, html, dictionary, jinja2

I have got problem with printing dictionary in HTML. I would like to print list of dictionaries called results = [{'first': 'John', 'last': 'Smith', 'age': 12}, ...] but printing values by ordered keys.
I have list of dictionaries and list with ordered keys like ['first', 'last', 'age'] called headers.

**Sample:**

```
{% for result in results %}
<tr>
    {% for header in headers %}
    <td>
         {{ result.header }}
    </td>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I know it's printing result['header'] but I would like to get result['first']. I need to do this like that because I have got different dictionaries with different headers and I would like to have one layout to display tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jinja2 (unlike for example Django template language) you can use methods with parameters, so you can use the dictionary `.get` method:

```
{{ result.get(header) }}
```